# Converting printed outputs using a dictionary to a string in python

Tags: python, string, variables, dictionary

I'm new to the world of Python and was hoping for a clean answer to my question. I have the following print output, which will output values to the console.

```
# Print out the train results.
print("-" * 20)
print("Train number: " + str(result['trainNumber']))
print("Destination: " + str(result['locationName']))
print("Departing at: " + str(result['departure_time']))
print("Platform: " + str(result['platform']))
print("Status: " + str(result['Status']))
print("Operator: " + str(result['operator']))
print("Estimated arrival at Feltham: " + result['ETA'].strftime("%H:%M")) # Format ETA as H:M
print ("Time now: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")))
print("Time until train: " + str(int(result['timeToTrain'])) + " minutes")
print("Chance of getting this train: " + result['chance'])
```

However, I want to convert these to a *single* multiline string to pass as a variable. Is this possible? I'm not sure how to deal with new lines - \n seems to cause issues, and the formats I've added for datetimes is causing a bit of a problem.

I want to keep using the result{} dictionary too - what's the best/cleanest solution here?

Edit: To clarify a little (having just learned about what the XY problem is), I am trying to run some python code on pythonista. I have the information I need in results{}, but I need to pass the same printed values to a single string variable so I can use it as part of a workflow on my phone. I want to keep formatting the same.

```
clipboard.set(output_text)
```

I guess what I'm asking here is what the cleanest way of coding this is, given that I'm also modifying the outputs from results{} with other formatting methods/functions.

Comment: Why are you trying to create " a single multiline string to pass as a variable"? Don't you have the info you need in the `result` dictionary already?

Comment: `print(a) print(b)` is basically equivalent to `print(a + "\n" + b)`. Please clarify what "`\n` seems to cause issues" means. Also, are you sure you don't have [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here?

Comment: Hey both, just hopefully clarified in my initial question.

Comment: Still unclear what you mean by 'convert these to a single multiline string to pass as a variable'. What are these? The strings you're printing? What do you mean by 'multiline string'? A string with newline characters in it? A string that has all of the things you've printed to different lines, but with no new lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a format string which looks up the values from the dictionary:

```
format_string = ('Train number: {trainNumber}\n'
                 'Destination: {locationName}\n'  # etc
                 'Estimated arrival at Feltham: {ETA:%H:%M}\n'
                 'Time now: {now:%H:%M}\n')  # etc
```

Usage:

```
from datetime import datetime

result = {'trainNumber': 192,
          'locationName': 'Wigan',
          'ETA': datetime(2017, 9, 4, 12, 23)}

print format_string.format(now=datetime.now(),
                           **result)
```

Output:

> Train number: 192
>   Destination: Wigan
>   Estimated arrival at Feltham: 12:23
>   Time now: 11:38

Answer (score 0):

Just use + to concatenate the strings.
Also, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")) is already a string, so the str is not needed.

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy(("-" * 20) + "\nTrain number: " + str(result['trainNumber'])   
+ "\nDestination: " + str(result['locationName']))
clipboard = pyperclip.paste()
```

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way to assign to a variable using triple quotes '"""', example below

```
var = """
{0}
Train number: {1}
Destination: {2}
Departing at: {3}
Platform: {4}
Status: {5}""".format(("-"*20),str(result['trainNumber']),str(result['locationName']),
str(result['departure_time']), str(result['platform']), str(result['Status']))
```